# What type of grease could I use to pack in my connector to prevent corrosion?

Tags: connector, corrosion

I am looking to protect a phoenix contact terminal which is exposed to the elements. When the units come back for servicing I can see that they have corrosion on the contact. I recall purchasing wire nuts pre-packed with grease for the very same reason. I'd like to buy a tub/tube of a similar grease to pack inside these connectors.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but I've just used a dab of vaseline (petroleum jelly) on RJ11/RJ45 jacks. I've also used a squirt of WD-40 to just keep the moisture off in some instances, but vaseline tends to do it for most cases.

Comment: Try "Light Bulb Grease", auto or boating supply stores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dielectric Grease. Cheap, non-conducting, doesn't harden over time. Any auto store will have it.

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking to protect a phoenix contact terminal which is exposed to the elements.

This is the main problem. Phoenix connectors are not sealed, and are not designed for outdoor use. They are also spring-contact type, with medium-low contact force. Change to a connector type more suited to outdoor use.

---

Dielectric grease itself is an *insulator*, which can interfere with normal metal contact, so should not be blindly "packed" into connectors.

For wire-nuts this doesn't apply, as the wires are crushed together with a high pressure. Same with crimp or crush-type splice connectors, as they bind on the wires very tightly, ensuring electrical connection. Most automotive lamps use a rather tough spring-connection, so can get away with dielectric grease, although I don't recommend it. Nowadays, most automotive connections use sealed connectors. As long as the seal holds, corrosion won't happen.

But for "softer" spring-connections, dielectric grease can actually *cause* connection issues. For instance, I just worked on an I/O card from an old machine, and the only thing wrong with it was the (gold-plated) backplane connector was packed with dielectric grease, resulting in poor pin contact and intermittent operation.

- **Use dielectric grease on electrical *connectors* to keep contaminants out of the *connector*, not on the metal contacts themselves.**  For instance, spark plugs should get a little grease in the boot, but none on the metal contacts.  Battery terminals can get coated with it (will collect dirt) but only *after* a dry, clean, tight mechanical connection is made. Headlamp connectors should be a sealing type, but DG can be used on the rubber seal and connector body to lubricate and ensure an airtight seal. *Keep it *out* of the pins - if the connector is truly sealed, corrosion won't happen.*
- **Do not use dielectric grease on any plug with gold-plated connectors.**  Gold should not corrode. If it did, your problem is much more serious than dielectric grease. Most gold connectors are low-force spring-type anyways. But you may be able to use dielectric grease on the *backside* of the connector, or use a sealing gasket, o-ring, cover, or some other way to seal the connection.  If a gold connection is intermittent with no corrosion, that connection needs *cleaned* -  the contaminants removed - not greased.  A good cleaner for this purpose would be a contact cleaner spray (not a pencil eraser, which introduces sulfur compounds and results in further corrosion!)

Answer (score 0):

Pure silicone dielectric grease can be used.  Its low viscosity does not interfere with the connection and serves to add some corrosion protection as well as increasing the usable mating cycles of the connector.  It is a ship-with for some marine electronics systems that use Phoenix style connectors.  Additionally, talk to your Phoenix FAE.  My local FAE has advised me that any of their connectors can be ordered pre-lubricated to increase the mating cycles, which in turns decreases the realized contact resistance for connections that have an increased number of matings.  That being said, the grease shouldn't be used where arcing might occur.  In true wet conditions, a connector for that environment should be used if possible.